# Meaningful statistic measure of data pairs

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, average, ratio

I have a dilemma.

I have pairwise data, (a,b), that represents some form of speed, whether it's miles/hour or megabits/second.  Let's say that we have the following set of data from measuring the "speed" of the same "car" on two different "courses" A and B under different conditions (say weather), ignoring the unit for now, and with apologies for my notations.

{(a,b)} = {(1, 4), (1, 2), (1, 1), (2, 1), (4, 1)}

There are a few ways to interpret the data:

1) If one believes that the "car" runs faster on "course" A and calculates the average of speed-up (a/b):

average speedup = (1/4 + 1/2 + 1/1 + 2/1 + 4/1)/5 = 1.55

Voila, "course" A makes the "car" go 55% faster than "course" B!

2) If one believes that the "car" runs faster on "course" B and calculates the average of speed-up (b/a):

average speedup = (4/1 + 2/1 + 1/1 + 1/2 + 1/4)/5 = 1.55

Voila, "course" B makes the "car" go 55% faster than "course" A!

3) If one believes say CDF is the right way to compare the data set, then it will be something like:

A: 1, 1, 1, 2, 4

B: 1, 1, 1, 2, 4

Voila, "courses" A and B are more or less identical.

Obviously, all three interpretations mask out important details, but at the same time, I am not able to come up with a good statistical measure to describe this set of data.  This is clearly just a toy example, but I am facing similar dilemmas interpreting real data.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  Do you just want people to suggest additional statistics besides the 3 listed?  You haven't given any criteria for what makes a statistic "good" for your problem.

Comment: My dilemma is that none of the three accurately captures what the data is saying.  I guess the data is almost saying that the two "courses" should not be directly compared, at least one should not use a single metric to capture the statistical difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide what is important for your situation. Let's say the average speed is important. Then you do a hypothesis test on the means. In this case a paired t-test might be appropriate. Or maybe a permutation test.

Maybe it's important to know if the speeds for A and B have the same distribution or not. Then a two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test could be applied.

A single metric could work for you. It just depends on what you really need to know.

Comment: thanks, soakley.  I appreciate the answer, and I am looking into KM two-sample test. Octave has such a function built-in.  I think if A and B are independent, this would work, but if not, we may have a joint distribution due to the nature of sampling, right? For paired t-test, I am not sure the underlying distribution is normal (I guess KM one-sample test could tell me).  In practice, most of the empirical distributions of data that I deal with are more long/fat tail rather than normal.